# Не понимаю работу функции в python

Tags: python, массивы, рекурсия

в данном примере, функция принимает матрицу `list[list[int]]` и разворачивает ее по спирали с левого верхнего угла в `list[int]` и отдает его через output когда функция завершает работу.

в примере решения указан данный вариант, но он возвращает `None` за место значения.

```
def traverse_matrix(matrix: list[list[int]], output: list[int] = None) -> list[int]:
    if output is None:
        output = []
    if not len(matrix):
        return output

    matrix = list(zip(*matrix[::-1]))
    output.extend(matrix[0][::-1])
    traverse_matrix(matrix[1:], output)
```

у меня получилось вернуть output, путем данной манипуляции.

```
def traverse_matrix(matrix: list[list[int]], output: list[int] = None) -> list[int]:
    if output is None:
        output = []
    if not len(matrix):
        return

    matrix = list(zip(*matrix[::-1]))
    output.extend(matrix[0][::-1])
    traverse_matrix(matrix[1:], output)

    return output
```

Обьясните пожалуйста, почему в первом примере, функция не прерывает работу когда попадет на `return`, а после продолжает что то делать. Первый вариант видимо, когда то работал (возможно).

Как работают эти функции?

Comment: Не прерывает работу после чего?

Comment: В первом примере `return` стоял в условном операторе, т.е. когда матрица пуста. Если она что-то да имеет (даже пустые подсписки), то программа, естественно, будет продолжать работать

Comment: спасибо, добрый человек!